# SSH config file?

Tags: mac, ssh

Is there a SSH config file (~/.ssh/config) information page with all attributes you can have in that file?

Who is managing the SSH protocol and its implementation in Mac (dont know what ssh client Mac uses)?

Comment: Belongs on server fault.

Comment: Would be better on Super User than Server Fault. This is a user issue, not an administrator issue.

Comment: the config files are all hidden in some deep directories, and they use a plist format, i messed with them at one point, but i don't remember where the files are, sorry.  Pretty much its all in an xml style formatting, instead of a simple unix type config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These links should help you:

- http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/ssh_config.5.html
- http://www.panix.com/help/sw.macosx-ssh.html

Answer (score 3):

Depends on your ssh client.

For OpenSSH there's `man ssh_config`.